# ¿Cómo detectar actualización (F5) en una página con React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

deseo saber como detectar que un usuario haya presionado F5 o actualizar en su navegador mientras está en cierta dirección de la página que estoy desarrollando con React, esto con el fin de mostrar una ventana de confirmación y ejecutar algunas funciones dependiendo de la respuesta del usuario (confirmar actualizar página o cancelar la actualización de la página).

Encontré este código y probé ponerlo dentro de mi functional component con React:

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    const isOK = confirm('Message');
    if (confirm('Successful Message')) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
    return '¿Desea recargar la página web?';
  };

return <div>Hola</div>

}

export default MyComponent;
```

La estructura del componente es solo de ejemplo de donde estoy poniendo la función con `window.onbeforeunload`.

Pero nunca se ejecuta cuando actualizo la página con el navegador.

**Edito**: he probado la función con solo:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return '¿Desea recargar la página web?';
};
```

Esto funciona, ¿cómo puedo personalizar ese mensaje y ejecutar acciones dependiendo cual botón presione?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

usando `window.onbeforeunload` esta correcto, lo que te esta pasando es porque al no ponerlo en un `useEffect` el código se esta ejecutando el código cada vez que el componente se tiene que refrescar

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const onUnload = () => "¿Quieres salir?";

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onUnload);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", onUnload);
  }, []);

  return <div>Hola</div>

}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: ¿En dónde puedo agregar funciones para que se ejecuten al presionar "Volver a cargar" o "Cancelar"?

Comment: no puedes agregar funciones ahi, solo puedes cambiar el texto

Comment: Probé eso que pusiste y nunca salía el mensaje. Necesito ejecutar funciones, como para guardar datos antes de que se actualice la página.